# Euler characteristic for CW complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Can someone help me of how to prove these two basic properties of Euler characteristics, but regarding finite $CW$ complexes.

$a)$ If $A$ and $B$ are two subcomplexes of a finite $CW$ complex $X$, then
$\chi(X)=\chi(A)+\chi(B)-\chi(A \cap B)$

$b)$If $A$ is a subcomplex of a finite $CW$ complex $X$, then $\chi (A)-\chi (X)+\chi (X/A)=1$

Yes, I have the definition, which says that for $X$ being a finite $CW$ complex, of dimension n, and for $a_i$ being the number of $i$-cells of $X$, we define the Euler characteristic as the alternating sum

$\chi (X)=a_0-a_1+a_2-...+(-1)^na_n$,

but I find this cell_consideration a bit abstract for rather direct calculation which it seems should be used here.

Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part (a):** You could apply the inclusion-exclusion principle to each of the $a_i$'s individually. In other words, the number of $0$-cells in $X$ is equal to the number of $0$-cells in $A$ plus the number of $0$-cells in $B$ minus the number of $0$-cells in $A \cap B$. The same is true for $1$-cells, and $2$-cells, and so on:
$$ a_0(X) = a_0(A) + a_0(B) - a_0(A \cap B), \\
a_1(X) = a_1(A) + a_1(B) - a_1(A \cap B), \\
a_2(X) = a_2(A) + a_2(B) - a_2(A \cap B), \\
\vdots$$

**Part (b):** When you quotient $X$ by $A$, you are shrinking $A$ to a point. That means you are replacing all the cells in $A$ with a single $0$-cell:
$$ a_0 (X/A) = a_0(X) - a_0(A) + 1, 
\\ a_1(X / A) = a_1(X) - a_1(A) , \\
a_2(X / A) = a_2(X) - a_2(A), \\
\vdots
$$

Comment: Rght! And do you know if there are any similar formulae to hold in case of the Poincare polynomial?

Comment: @Eurydice Oops, I was being stupid - no it doesn't hold for the Poincare polynomial, because the coefficients of the Poincare polynomial are the dimensions of the **homology groups**, whereas our $a_i$'s are the number of $i$-cells. For example, think of $X$ as a circle, built from two 0-cells joined by two 1-cells. Let $A$ and $B$ be the two "halves" of the circle, so each of $A$ and $B$ is a closed interval. Then $A \cap B$ is the disjoint union of two points. The Poincare polynomials are $P(X) = 1 + t$, $P(A) = 1$, $P(B) = 1$, $P(A \cap B) = 2$.