# Euler Characteristic for relative cell-complex, show that $\chi(A)-\chi(X)+\chi(X,A)=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a finite cell-complex and $A\subset X$ be a sub-cell complex.

The post has been answered here: [Euler characteristic for CW complexes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292683/euler-characteristic-for-cw-complexes) asked about the proof for $$\chi(A)-\chi(X)+\chi(X/A)=1.$$ This question induces a similar question about what $\chi(A)-\chi(X)+\chi(X,A)$ is.

I know that Euler characteristic is the alternating sum of the number of cells in each dimension. That is $$\chi(A)=c_{0}(A)-c_{1}(A)+c_{2}(A)-\cdots+(-1)^nc_{n}(A)$$ $$\chi(X)=c_{0}(X)-c_{1}(X)+c_{2}(X)-\cdots+(-1)^nc_{n}(X).$$

Also, we know that the cellular chain complex of $(X,A)$ is given by the quotient groups $$C_{k}(X,A)=C_{k}(X)/C_{k}(A)=\mathbb{Z}^{\{\#\ \text{of}\ k-\text{cells in}\ X\ \text{but not in}\ A\}}$$ Does this imply that $c_{k}(X,A)=c_{k}(X)-c_{k}(A)$?

If so, then $\chi(A)-\chi(X)+\chi(X,A)=0$... but this seems not correct... I actually expect it to equal $1$.

Is my proof correct or I am missing something? Thank you!

Comment: I think you can use the result that you linked to, along with the fact that $H_n(X, A) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ when $A\subset X$ is a cell-subcomplex. In other words $\chi(X/A) = \tilde{\chi}(X/A) + 1 = \chi(X, A) + 1$. Then the sum you're looking for really is $0$.

Comment: What exactly are you taking as the definition of $\chi(X, A)$? (My argument above assumes it's defined as $\sum_i (-1)^i rank(H_i(X, A))$)

Comment: If $c_k(X, A)$ denotes the number of $k$-cells in $X$ that are not in $A$ then by definition it is equal to $c_k(X) - c_k(A)$. So if your definition of $\chi(X, A)$ is as the alternating sum of the $c_k(X, A)$ then you're going to get $\chi(X, A) = \chi(X) - \chi(A)$, essentially by definition.

Comment: @William sorry for the late reply. For $\chi(X,A)$, yes, I can use your definition with betti number, but I believe the initial definition is the alternating sum of the number of different dimensional cells in $(X,A)$

Comment: @William If it is $0$, then it is also okay. I am not sure if it is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @William yeah. it is 0, I am pretty sure now. I will answer my own post couple days later. Thank you for your comment!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion you're having ultimately comes from the fact that $H_*(X,A;\Bbb Z)$ is not isomorphic to $H_*(X/A;\Bbb Z)$, but rather to the reduced homology $\tilde H_*(X/A)$. The former is larger by exactly a copy of $\Bbb Z$ in degree zero, so $$\chi(X/A) = \chi(X,A) + 1.$$